# How do I change my Live ID login?

Tags: windows-live

I have looked at every option available on http://account.live.com, and while I can add alternate email addresses there seems to be no way to change the primary one.

How do I change the primary email address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When logging in it shows your account summary with a Change next to your e-mail. Click this and it will have an option saying Change My Live ID with further instructions.

- Login to http://account.live.com
- On the account summary page under your name next to the e-mail address click Change
- Enter your password under verify your information
- Choice between a new Live ID or your own e-mail address
- Click Save.

Comment: "On the account summary page under your name next to the e-mail address click Change" -- my old account doesn't have this link. Interestingly, the new account I just created with a correct email address does have this link. Hurrah for MS...